# Container div overflows parent instead of showing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Trying to have a container div display an horizontal scrollbar when its child is too long. Instead, the container div itself overflows its parent.

Here is my code:

```css
.root {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span>Hello World</span>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, the green div would not overflow it's parent (the blue div) nor have a scrollbar. The horizontal scrollbar should appear in the `container` class div.

Comment: add `min-width:0` to right element

Comment: Hi Gabriel, welcome to SO!  I'd really like for you to get an answer to your question, one thing that has helped many in the past: Providing context around what you have tried / what you've learned trying to solve the issue.

Comment: @seeldotme thanks, already got an answer :) but will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: hidden` to `.right`:

```
.right {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

This will ensure that the red box doesn't overflow its parent and will allow scrolling within it.